# Bivariate distribution for log returns of stocks

Tags: distributions, bivariate

I'm aware that the log returns of securities are often considered to follow Levy alpha-stable, or truncated Levy Flight distributions, and sometimes t-distributions or normal mixtures too. What about bivariate distributions for returns? I.e. for the log returns of two securities? Which distributions are considered standard for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options, in particular, you can use a bivariate t distribution or a bivariate copula distribution with t marginals or any other kind of marginals. See [this example](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/tcop) for the t-copula and [this one](http://www.rpubs.com/FJRubio/PostOBayesT) for the t distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it follows a  multivariate hyperbolic secant distribution.  I would still work with the raw form, however as you can more easily model the intertemporal budget constraint.

See:
Harris, D.E. (2017) The Distribution of Returns. Journal of Mathematical Finance, 7, 769-804